# When I delete one part, it deletes another part with it. How can I fix this? **FIXED

Tags: modeling

So, when I was modeling a hovercraft in Blender, I wanted to delete a part. So, I did. No problem, right? But there was a problem. It deleted another part with it. I checked, and there seems to be no connection between the two. In fact, the part isn't even listed in the collection explorer. (The panel on the right, idk what's it's called.) Anyway, if someone could help me on this, that would be great. Thank you! [image: As you can see, in the explorer panel, on one thing is selected, but in the viewport, theres 2 parts selected.]

EDIT: I fixed it. It turns out I was selecting the wrong object. Sorry.

Comment: Hello, it's a bit too vague, what do you call a "part"? Is it a mesh? An Object? A collection instance? Etc. At least show some screenshots

Comment: It was a Metaball. And I just added some screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metaballs are a bit special, from what I understand, if you want to select only one metaball in your metaball system, use the thin line around the metaball object, don't select the metaball itself, otherwise it will select all the metaballs of the same system:

[image]

Also, as precised by Vklidu, don't delete the first metaball otherwise its children will be deleted as well. And if you change the name of a metaball it will exit from its system.

Comment: "Metaballs are a bit special ..." yeah :) First metaball added to a scene is like a mother and others are children. Deleting mother children's are gone. The structure states on naming. There has to be one object without number like "Mball" as mother and children as "Mball.001", "Mball.002". Changing core name creates a new meta ecosystem. Deleting number associates a new mother.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: @ vklidu, I knew it was working as a system but I didn't even knew there was a mother, thanks for the precision, even weirder than I thought   ;)

Answer (score 0):

The other part must have been a Instance of the part you deleted!
please do add some screenshots or a blend, it will be easy to understand your problem.